# How to convert the following SQL query to a Linq query in C#

Tags: c#, linq

```
select 
    t.Ticketid, t.subject, t.createdby,
    count(TicketConversationId) as counts 
from 
    dbo.ticket t 
join 
    dbo.TicketConversation tc on t.ticketid = tc.ticketid
group by 
    t.Ticketid, t.subject, t.createdby
```

Code:

```
var Result = from t1 in Tickets 
             join t2 in TicketConversations on t1.TicketId equals t2.TicketId 
             select new { t1.TicketId, t1.Subject , comments = t2.TicketConversationId };
```

Comment: Please provide some linq attempt for what you are trying to do

Comment: Also what are you using? EF?

Comment: Yes it is using EF

Comment: @SukhenduChakraborty - Good. Then please show some attempt so we can help from there. Even starting with just selecting the data from database.

Comment: var Result = from t1 in Tickets join t2 in TicketConversations on t1.TicketId equals t2.TicketId 
select new  {  t1.TicketId, t1.Subject , comments=t2.TicketConversationId};

Comment: Please add your model classes to the question. Typically, I would expect a navigation property between `Ticket` and `TicketConversation`, then writing explicit join should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to add the counting and grouping for your query use `GroupBy`:

```
var result = from t1 in Tickets 
             join t2 in TicketConversations on t1.TicketId equals t2.TicketId 
             group t2.TicketConversationId by new { t.Ticketid, t.Subject, t.createdby } into g
             select new { 
                 t1.TicketId, 
                 t1.Subject , 
                 t1.CreatedBy, 
                 Count = g.Count() };
```

*Notice that as you are using EF, if you properly define the [Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx) you will not need to explicitly write the join but just `t1.Conversations.Count()` or similar.*

---

As all you need is to count the number of records in `t2` that match you can use `group join`

```
var result = from t1 in Tickets
             join t2 in TicketConversations on t1.TicketId equals t2.TicketId into con
             select new {
                 t1.TicketId,
                 t1.Subject,
                 t1.CreatedBy,
                 Count = con.Count()
             };
```

Comment: @SukhenduChakraborty - If this helped you solve the problem please consider marking question as solved